# MySQL ran out of disk creating an index, now I can't reclaim my disk

Tags: mysql, index, disk-space, temporary-tables

I've run a command on my MySQL database to add an index to a large table containing 8 million records (ironically so I could start deleting some of them):

`CREATE  INDEX`index_audit_logs_on_id`ON`audit_logs``

As part of that, MySQL will create a temporary table. I have 40GB of total disk, and this table is 25 GB, so I ran out of disk space while doing this. My commmand errored:

`` Mysql2::Error: The table '#sql-2b9f_2178' is full: CREATE  INDEX `index_audit_logs_on_id` ON `audit_logs` ``

However, I am still out of disk space now!

`/dev/sdc               40G   38G   20K 100% /var/lib/mysql`

I don't see this temporary table. Is there something I can do to reclaim by 15GB of disk space?

Comment: I have found this resource describing what I believe is my problem: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html  -- however there are no .frm files I can use. When I try copying the original table's .frm file, renaming it to `#sql-2b9f_2178.frm`, and attempting to delete `#mysql50#ssql-2b9f_2178.frm`, it does not lead to any disk being reclaimed, and only an error in the log

Comment: I was able to track down how I can see tables - it looks like this table is not even in the MySQL data dictionary, so it is not in use by a temporary table http://www.markleith.co.uk/2009/01/19/innodb-table-and-tablespace-monitors/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no temporary table taking up this space, after all. I was able to verify that by turning on the mysql monitor as documented here for my version of mysql (5.1):

http://www.markleith.co.uk/2009/01/19/innodb-table-and-tablespace-monitors/

I ran the following query, then checked my error log to see the table monitor output: `create table innodb_table_monitor (a int) engine = innodb;` Then delete the monititor (`delete table innodb_table_monitor`).This confirms that I do not have a table.

However - I still do not have disk space! It turns out that mysql will never return space to the OS:

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=1341

I can confirm that this is indeed 'free space':

```
mysql> SELECT table_schema "Data Base Name",  sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "Data Base Size in MB",  sum( data_free )/ 1024 / 1024 "Free Space in MB"  FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;
+------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| Data Base Name         | Data Base Size in MB | Free Space in MB |
+------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
| deepthought_production |       23939.10937500 |  273756.00000000 |
| information_schema     |           0.00781250 |       0.00000000 |
| mysql                  |           0.62998486 |       0.00000000 |
+------------------------+----------------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.14 sec)
```

This is a comment @a_vlad left which appears to be the best solution at this point:

> As solution - dump over network, it could be long but it work. Change settings for file_per_table, stop mysql drop ibdata and start mysql, than import dump back. Before this possible - delete unnecessary data for reduce dump size

Answer (score 2):

**CREATE INDEX**

If the files `#sql-2b9f_2178.*` were left behind by the failed operation, `rm` them.

The `CREATE INDEX` was copying the table over to create the index.  This is the new copy, before it is swapped into place.

Two important bits of info:  What ENGINE is used for the table?  What version of MySQL?  There have been a number of changes in this area; I suspect you have an antique version and/or are using MyISAM.  Recommend upgrading.

**Deleting**

Do you have *any* index on the table?  If so, then the following blog has a number of techniques that *may* be viable for helping clean up the table:  [*Big Deletes*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/big-deletes/) .

However, there may still be an issue of recovering disk space.  So...

If the amount of data you need to keep is small enough to fit, then focus on this part of the blog:  [*Deleting more than half a table*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/big-deletes/#deleting-more-than-half-a-table) .

Still, there may be a problem.

If MyISAM, no problem -- simply `DROP` the old table and `RENAME TABLE`.

If InnoDB, then you really need to be using `innodb_file_per_table = ON`.  Set this globally, and re-login in order to get the value.

But... There may still be problems.  We can continue this discussion after you have answered my questions.

Comment: The table is using InnoDB and I am using MySQL Ver 5.1.66

Comment: I am not currently using innodb_file_per_table, everything is in one giant file

Comment: Single file mode - never return space to OS. As solution - dump over network, it could be long but it work. Change settings for file_per_table, stop mysql drop ibdata and start mysql, than import dump back. Before this possible - delete unnecessary data for reduce dump size.

Comment: If there is a `.ibd` file with the tablename, then it is file_per_table.

Comment: it is indeed OFF, verified with `mysql> show global variables like 'innodb_file_per_table';`

Comment: No, Dan, that only verifies that _future_ tables will go into `ibdata1`.  You _could_ have turned it ON before creating the table.  Or turned it on, done an `ALTER`, then turned it off.

Comment: But, anyway, a_vlad's comment is probably the direction to take.  (Perhaps the only viable solution.)

Comment: Minor edit to a_vlad's suggestion:  do the deletes using my chunking recommendation _before_ the dump.  (Less to dump.)